# Exception when running cocos2dxsample project(Raywenderlich tutorial Cocos2D-X for iOS and Android)

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am following Cocos2D-X for iOS and Android: Getting Started tutorial from [Raywenderlich  site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started).

I have downloaded the android project from create-android-project.sh command as stated in the site. When I try to run the project in eclipse I got the following logs:

```
09-26 13:04:05.081: W/dalvikvm(517): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/a/samplecocos2dxandroid21;
09-26 13:04:05.081: W/dalvikvm(517): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/a/samplecocos2dxandroid21;)
09-26 13:04:05.081: D/AndroidRuntime(517): Shutting down VM
09-26 13:04:05.081: W/dalvikvm(517): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null 
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)   
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.a.samplecocos2dxandroid21.<clinit>(samplecocos2dxandroid21.java:106)
09-26 13:04:05.091: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  ... 15 more
```

android ndk, android sdk path setting and change an create-android-project.sh already done.
Can somebody please tell me where I am wrong and what is the solution of that..,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't run the build_native.sh so that your game is not built to a shared lib, that is why it complain about Can't find library

Comment: Thanks for the answer you are right,  Now I run build_native.sh from terminal and then import the project in eclipse, when i try to run it, it give me different error in log and in emulator screen goes black and then back to emulator home with in a second without any message.

Comment: 09-27 10:35:28.135: E/StrictMode(168): class com.android.launcher2.Launcher; instances=2; limit=1
09-27 10:35:28.135: E/StrictMode(168): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.launcher2.Launcher; instances=2; limit=1
09-27 10:35:28.135: E/StrictMode(168):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
THIS IS THE ERROR LOG MESSAGE IN THE LOGCAT.

Comment: @user1690588 if you are using cocos2d 2.x, please test the program on device instead of on Emulator, it did have some known issue on Emulator

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am using cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2 and result is same on device(black screen for a second then exit without any message)(using Karbonn smart tab 1).

Comment: @user1690588 would you mind to set the LogCat Filter to All messages and see what happens? usually there will be a large chunk of green code there. do not set filter to your app coz it doesn't provide any helpful info.

Comment: I did some research and realize that your Tab processer is MIPS-based, which is not supported by cocos2d-x yet (only arm are supported at the moment, although there are some developer reported it works fine on particular MIPS-based devices, but most of them simply crashed). you can find more info here http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/15341

Comment: Thanks for your answer and quick responses. Now I have to search another device to test it. Thanks once again..,.